# How to show undo and redo actions in toolbar in rcp application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I am working on an rcp application with a toolbar for quick access to certain actions, including undo and redo. My problem is that these two specific actions don't show up in the toolbar. I have located the cause to the `workbench.xmi` file that is generated when the application launches. A tag `persistedState` with an attribute `key="persp.hiddenItems"` contains `persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo,persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo` in the `value="..."` attribute. If I delete these entries from `workbench.xmi`, the undo and redo actions show up in the toolbar as they should.

My question is: What can I do so that `org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo` and `org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo` don't end up in this attribute to begin with?

I originally used eclipse neon without this problem, but when updating to eclipse 2018-12 this started happening.

**Edit:**

I finally got it to work by changing the IDs of my undo and redo actions to something else. I had to set the ID with `setId(...)` and `setActionDefinedId(...)` in the actions' constructors, and then the commands had to be defined in `plugin.xml` under `<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">` in a `<command id="..." name="Undo"></command>` tag.

This solutions feels more like a workaround than an actual solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set by the `hiddenToolBarItem` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point.

The `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in uses this to disable these tool-bar items:

```xml
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension targetID="*">
         <!--
              disable "print" button which is defined by org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory.PRINT
              and contributed by org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder
         -->
         <hiddenToolBarItem id="print" />
         <!--
              disable "undo" button which is defined by org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory.UNDO
              and contributed by org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder
         -->
         <hiddenToolBarItem id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo" />
         <!--
              disable "redo" button which is defined by org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory.REDO
              and contributed by org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder
         -->
         <hiddenToolBarItem id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo" />
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
```

I don't see a way to clear this other than leaving out the plug-in.

Comment: The application seems to need `org.eclipse.ui.ide`, so leaving it out wouldn't work for me. Another thing that I've tried is to give my undo- and redo actions different IDs, which seems to somewhat work. The problem is that exceptions are printed to the console. I'll update the question with this information.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working by changing the IDs. I'll update my questing with what I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Undo/Redo   disappeared after upgrading to 2019 eclipse.

One way to override the hardcoding in org.eclipse.ui.ide global perspective setting is to modify the perspective state directly. E.g. in ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen()

```
        WorkbenchPage page = (WorkbenchPage) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
            String str = page.getCurrentPerspective().getPersistedState().get(ModeledPageLayout.HIDDEN_ITEMS_KEY);
            str=str.replace("persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo,", "");
            str=str.replace("persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo,", "");
            page.getCurrentPerspective().getPersistedState().put(ModeledPageLayout.HIDDEN_ITEMS_KEY,str);
```