# Undo and Redo options does not appear in application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have created an eclipse application. When I launch the application for the first time I can see undo and redo in the toolbar. When I close the application and launch it again, the options disappear.

I have figure out that the workbench.xmi is updating these actions in the hidden items.

```
<persistedState key="persp.hiddenItems" value="persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo,persp.hideToolbarSC:org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo"/>
```

I have tried clearing the persisted state and it works fine. But I do not want to clear the persisted state. Can anyone explain why it is being added to hidden perspective and how can i avoid the problem.

Comment: I think that usually comes from a `hiddenToolBarItem` item in a `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point. So search through the plugins for an extension point doing that.

Comment: I will check on that for sure. But in that case it should not appear in the first launch right?

Comment: @greg-449 I checked and there is no code in the plugins I defined does that. But I saw your answer on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342472/how-to-show-undo-and-redo-actions-in-toolbar-in-rcp-application), org.eclipse.ui.ide does that. Is there anyway to override that.

Comment: I don't think you can override it. The person asking that other question seems to have added new toolbar items with different ids

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I kind of did not understand his workaround. Setting the id with _setId(...) and setActionDefinedId(...) in the actions' constructors_. Can you explain this part please.

Comment: Sounds like they defined their own Undo / Redo classes based on the `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action` class.